# Probelms Installing Exchange 2010 Installation Organization Prep failed|can't Prepare Schema Server

Tags: exchange-2010, installation, schema

I currently am running two exchange servers. I am running an Windows 2003 server with Exchange 2007 and I am also running a windows 2003 with Exchange 2003. I am adding two new Windows 2008 R2 servers that will be running Exchange 2010 (64 bit). My master schema server 2003 (32bit)

During the install of exchange everything is going smoothly until I get to the organization prep. At this point of the install I am getting the following error:

The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(): install-ExcchangeSchema - LdapFileName (&roleInstallPath + "Setup/Data/"+$RoleSchemaPrefix + "schema0.ldf")

"was run:
"C:\Windows\Temp\ExchangeSetup\Setup\Data\PostExchange2003_schema0.ldf:.

C:\Windows\Temp\ExchangeSetup\Setup\Data\PostExchange2003_schema0.ldf

In researching this error I found the following article that told me to insert the exchange 2010 DVD into my schema master server and run some command prompts.

https://www.conetrix.com/Blog/post/Exchange-2010-Installation-Error-Organization-Preparation-Failed.aspx

This article is linked from previous article and has the command prompts I am using

http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000442.htm

I have done this and tried to run the command it suggests but I get the following error

Command: Setup /PrepareLegacyExchangePermissions

When I run this command on the schema master server I get the following error.

C:\Windows\MSexchange2010>setup /PrepareLegacyExchangePermissions The image file C:\Windows\MSexchange2010\setup.com is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine

My Exchange install is 64 bit and my schema server is 32 bit. Could this be the problem? Any other suggestions on resolving this issue would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it looks like it is: http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-deployment-preparing-active-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with running the upgrade on the Schema Master is that you're trying to run 64-bit code on a 32-bit operating system. Nothing to do with the versions of Windows and Exchange involved, though it does sound like you're running a woefully out-of-date and untidy environment.

Frankly it sounds like you should tidy up your current Exchange org and upgrade the DCs to something more reasonable before proceeding anyway, but there *are* ways to upgrade the schema in a forest with only 32-bit DCs as follows:

*Install a temporary 64-bit DC*. Transfer Schema Master role. Do what you need to do. Remove DC afterwards if you need to (be careful about doing that if you install a newer version of Windows as the 64-bit DC). There is nothing special about a schema master after all, it's just a DC with a FSMO role assigned and moving this role around should not be a problem.

Frankly what I've suggested above makes me feel a bit cheap and sleazy just for suggesting it, but it should work just fine. *You really should be moving towards proper, permanent deployed 64-bit DCs on a more modern operating system as a matter of urgency though.*

There is another way. It's a bit more effort maybe, but again it will work.

> Forest/Domain Preparation - With Exchange Server 2010, you will need to leverage a 64-bit operating system to perform the schema extension and forest/domain preparation work. Hopefully you have 64-bit Active Directory servers deployed (or are planning to deploy them) and this won't be an issue. In the event that you do not have 64-bit Active Directory servers, you can install a 64-bit member server (physical or virtual) into the forest root domain, place it in the schema master's AD site, and apply the schema and forest preparations; for domain preparation, you can either update all domains by leveraging the /preparealldomains setup switch, or by removing/joining the 64-bit member server to each domain in the forest that you need to update.

(Taken from http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/05/19/3407510.aspx).
This "64-bit member server" can of course be the Exchange 2010 server.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rob. I am going to look into updating active directory servers before I proceed any further on installing exchange 2010. I had decided to go down the path of doing the exchange servers first with a goal of getting rid of the Exchange 2003 system. Sounds like I will need to start with the AD first. Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Check supported Active Directory environments here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx

I would highly recommend upgrading your AD servers first.

Comment: That maybe what I end up having to do. Thanks for the info